# convert time zone and minus x amount of time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time

I've been trying to get the following to work but I always seem get some sort of error..

1. get time from user input
2. use said time as variable
3. convert said time to JST
4. take away $duration (minutes) from time to give new time.

It would be something along the lines of code below.

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Please enter hour: " hour
read -p "Please enter minute: " minute
read -p "Please enter duration: " duration

jptime=$(TZ=JST date --date $hour$minute)

newtime=$(date -d "$jptime" "-$duration minutes")

echo "$newtime"
```

Comment: This may not solve your problem completely, but shouldn't `$hour$minute` be separated by a colon? ---> `$hour : $minute`

Comment: It can be, though it seems to work fine without, such as: 1154 or 0532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a language with a good datetime library. For example, perl

```
perl -MDateTime -E '
  ($hour, $minute, $duration) = @ARGV; 
  $fmt = "%F %T %Z";
  $local = DateTime->now(time_zone=>"local")->set(hour=>$hour, minute=>$minute, second=>0);
  say $local->strftime($fmt);
  $jp = $local->clone->set_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo"); 
  say $jp->strftime($fmt); 
  $jp2 = $jp->subtract(minutes => $duration); 
  say $jp2->strftime($fmt);
' 8 0 45
```

```
2015-01-17 08:00:00 EST
2015-01-17 22:00:00 JST
2015-01-17 21:15:00 JST
```

or Tcl

```
hour=8
minute=0
duration=45
export hour minute duration
tclsh <<'END'
  set fmt "%Y-%m-%d %T %Z"
  set t [clock scan "$env(hour):$env(minute) today"]
  puts [clock format $t -format $fmt]
  puts [clock format $t -format $fmt -timezone "Asia/Tokyo"]
  puts [clock format [clock add $t -$env(duration) minutes] -format $fmt -timezone "Asia/Tokyo"]
END
```

```
2015-01-17 08:00:00 EST
2015-01-17 22:00:00 JST
2015-01-17 21:15:00 JST
```

---

Per your comment:

```
 perl -MDateTime -E '
    ($hour, $minute, $duration) = @ARGV;
    say uc DateTime->now(time_zone=>"local")
                   ->set(hour=>$hour, minute=>$minute, second=>0)
                   ->set_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo")
                   ->subtract(minutes => $duration)
                   ->strftime("%a %H:%M");
' 8 0 45 >| output.file
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the perl script could help, is there any way to make it echo the new time to a file?

Comment: exactly what output do you need?

Comment: eg. SUN 08:51 - dd hh:mm